# resize the application to snap view programatically

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps

I am developing a win store application, user can launch other file/application from my application. At that point, I want to keep my application in front of user in the "snap view"

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010028/how-to-change-a-grid-layout-when-orientation-is-changed/23010540#23010540

Comment: The app A is running in full-screen mode by default, if I launch other app B from existing app A, app A will be suspended/hidden. What I want is that app A keep alive and is display in snap view mode (1/4 screen).

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 8.0, there wasn't a way to control this. In Windows 8.1, the Windows.System.Launcher API--namely the LaunchFileAsync and LaunchUriAsync methods that take a LauncherOptions argument--added support for the [LauncherOptions.DesiredRemainingView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcheroptions.desiredremainingview.aspx) property. This gives you the kind of control you're looking for here--in your scenario you'd want to use the value ViewSizePreference.UseMinimum in the DesiredRemainingView property.